# Proving worst case running time of QuickSort

Tags: recursion, analysis, equation, recurrence

I am trying to perform asymptotic analysis on the following recursive function for an efficient way to power a number.  I am having trouble determining the recurrence equation due to having different equations for when the power is odd and when the power is even.  I am unsure how to handle this situation. I understand that the running time is theta(logn) so any advice on how to proceed to this result would be appreciated.

```
Recursive-Power(x, n):
if n == 1
   return x
if n is even
   y = Recursive-Power(x, n/2)
   return y*y
else
   y = Recursive-Power(x, (n-1)/2)
   return y*y*x
```

Answer (score 3):

In any case, the following condition holds:

```
T(n) = T(floor(n/2)) + Θ(1)
```

where `floor(n)` is the biggest integer not greater than `n`.

Since `floor` doesn't have influence on results, the equation is informally written as:

```
T(n) = T(n/2) + Θ(1)
```

You have guessed the asymptotic bound correctly. The result could be proved using Substitution method or Master theorem. It is left as an exercise for you.